# Is it possible to replace the SQLite library in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sqlite

On Linux I was able to use the JSON1 extension by default on a layer from a SpatiaLite database connection, but on Windows (QGIS 3.0 via OSGeo4W) it isn't enabled. Is it possible to replace the SQLite/SpatiaLite library with one where JSON1 is enabled, and if yes, how?

**Update**: JSON1 is enabled as of osgeo4w's sqlite3 3.17.0-4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that JSON1 can be compiled as a loadable extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715178/how-to-enable-the-json1-extension-for-sqlite3-in-php but then it should be loaded before it can be used and QGIS probably does not do that. It may be possible to acquire sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.exe which have JSON1 compiled in by default and try is QGIS happens to work with them but strange things can happen. The safe way would be to compile the whole stack SQLite-GDAL-QGIS from the scratch which is not trivial on Windows.

Consider writing mail to osgeo4w-dev mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/osgeo4w-dev and suggest to compile SQLite with JSON1 enabled.